# SharePoint Modern Custom Footer SPFx Customizer - Multiple scrollbars

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions, footer, applicationcustomizers

We have created a custom footer using SPFx application Customizer to provide information like social media icons, feedback button, site map (html) etc.

This is now occupying more than 90% of content area providing vertical scroll to see the content. We, then using CSS setting footer div contents position to absolute so that when user scrolls to bottom of page then only footer visible.

Problem here is multiple scrollbar appearing which is very annoying. Footer is not placing on bottom of page rather screen bottom - which might be the issue.

Any help is highly appreciated

[image]